# How do I time a process in c++?

Tags: c++, eclipse, timer

I'm working on a project where I'm to time the creation of fork() and pthread_create(). We're supposed to time how long it takes to do each of these tasks by using system calls to create a personalized timer class. For assistance, the professor has told us to check man -k time.

I'm new to both using system calls and using man pages for documentation, so I'm entirely lost. So far the code I'm trying to get working is this:

```
#include "Timer.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <signal.h>
#include <ctime>
#include <time.h>
using namespace std;
Timer::Timer() {
    timer_t * tid;
    timer_create(CLOCK_REALTIME, NULL, tid);
    int time = timer_gettime(tid, 0);
    cout<<time;
}
```

When compiling, eclipse tosses me these errors:

```
undefined reference to 'timer_create', line 20
undefined reference to 'timer_gettime', line 21
```

The internet has pointed me in the direction of including the -lrt library when compiling, but I can't find anything that says how to do that, suggesting that perhaps it's entirely wrong.

So, am I on the right path? If I am, how am I supposed to get this code working?

## Edit:

I got the clock() based timer working. The downside is that we're timing fork(), which isn't registering as taking any time at all when timing it. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this

```
time_t start,end;
start=clock();//predefined  function in c

//after the user defined function does its work

end=clock();
t=(end-start)/CLOCKS_PER_SEC;
```